# Unable to show the subtitle in pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, emacs, org-mode

I have a code block as follows:

```
#+LATEX_CLASS: article
#+TITLE: Lecture 1: Introduction
#+SUBTITLE: Course Name
#+AUTHOR: My Name
#+EMAIL: myname@nowhere.com
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage{charter}
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil

* Introduction:
```

I want to display the course name as `#+subtitle` but it is not showing up. It was working earlier but not now. I searched various answers but nothing is giving a specific answer.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to happen? Latex classes normally does not provide interfaces for subtitle so a better question would be what exactly is org more than de converting this into? (from a latex point of view)

Comment: I need a title for my document and a subtitle. Org documentation says that `#+SUBTITLE` is available and I have used earlier.

Comment: Then yuo should probably go back to an example that works, convert it to file latex (I think is is C-c C-e l l), not directly to PDF, then  compare the two latex files. As article mode does not support subtitle, I would not be surprised that it is ignored.

Comment: I have removed `article` mode. Even the earlier version didn't have `article` mode. The only difference was `(require 'ox-latex)
(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
          '("koma-article"
             "\\documentclass{scrartcl}"
             ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
             ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
             ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
             ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
             ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}")))` which was komarticle and working fine.